# Report Issue Genexus 16 Trial

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd, genexus-gam, genexus-dbret

When I tried to pressed F5 to generate my knowledge base in Genexus 16 trial. There's have such an error 
 "GeneXus Account service exception: "Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'". Then I tried to uninstall this program and install again, but have nothing fixed it. And still giving the same error. It would be very thankful if you guys can give me some idea to fix the issues.Thank You

Answer (score 1):

The functionality for Database Reverse Engineering is only available into the Full version.

You can download the full version from here:
https://www.genexus.com/en/developers/downloadcenter?data=5879;;

The Trial version has only deploy to cloud option for prototyping, that is to say, you will not be able to retrieve information from local data stores.

Let me know if you want to try the full version.
Best regards